# Validating input field if value is 0 then ignore

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, paypal

I need help, how can I ignore the input fields if the value is "0".. in javascript

So basically if the value is "0" do not send the the content to paypal as paypal would give an error if you send it "0"

Idea is for a user to select a product  WHITE or BLACK and the quantity .. say the user only wants 2 black items and 0 white then it should only send whatever has a value of 1 or more to paypal.

What I need is the code for it to work.. I'll be more than glad to send a PAYPAL donation for your CODE...

Thanks for your help..

```
<form method="post" name="mainForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="george@360mix.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">


<!--First Item-->
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="WHITE Helping Hand">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="WHITE-HH">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="10.00">
 <select name="quantity_1" value="">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
</p>

<!--Second Item--> 
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="BLACK Helping Hand">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="BLACK-HH">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="10.00">
 <select name="quantity_2" value="">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
</p>
<br>

<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.360mix.com/thankyou.html">
<input type="image" src="http://images.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but22.gif" border="0" name="submit" width="87" height="23" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Comment: disable those 0 fields in the form's onsubmit event listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well try the example below. The idea is to check for every quantity if zero. If not, assign the next item number.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function prepareForm() {
                var index = 1;

                var q1 = document.getElementById('quantity_1').value;

                if (q1 > 0) {
                    document.getElementById('item_name_1').setAttribute('name', 'item_name_' + index);
                    document.getElementById('item_number_1').setAttribute('name', 'item_number_' + index);
                    document.getElementById('amount_1').setAttribute('name', 'amount_' + index);
                    document.getElementById('quantity_1').setAttribute('name', 'quantity_' + index);
                    index++;
                } else {
                    // reset (in case back button is pressed)
                    document.getElementById('item_name_1').setAttribute('name', '');
                    document.getElementById('item_number_1').setAttribute('name', '');
                    document.getElementById('amount_1').setAttribute('name', '');
                    document.getElementById('quantity_1').setAttribute('name', '');                 
                }

                var q2 = document.getElementById('quantity_2').value;

                if (q2 > 0) {
                    document.getElementById('item_name_2').setAttribute('name', 'item_name_' + index);
                    document.getElementById('item_number_2').setAttribute('name', 'item_number_' + index);
                    document.getElementById('amount_2').setAttribute('name', 'amount_' + index);
                    document.getElementById('quantity_2').setAttribute('name', 'quantity_' + index);
                    index++;
                } else {
                    // reset (in case button is pressed)
                    document.getElementById('item_name_2').setAttribute('name', '');
                    document.getElementById('item_number_2').setAttribute('name', '');
                    document.getElementById('amount_2').setAttribute('name', '');
                    document.getElementById('quantity_2').setAttribute('name', '');                 
                }

                if (index == 1) {
                        // in index is still one, then all quantities are zero
                        return false; // do not submit
                }

                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<form method="post" name="mainForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" onSubmit="return prepareForm();">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="george@360mix.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">


<!--First Item-->
<p>
<input type="hidden" id="item_name_1" value="WHITE Helping Hand">
<input type="hidden" id="item_number_1" value="WHITE-HH">
<input type="hidden" id="amount_1" value="10.00">
 <select id="quantity_1">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
</p>

<!--Second Item--> 
<p>
<input type="hidden" id="item_name_2" value="BLACK Helping Hand">
<input type="hidden" id="item_number_2" value="BLACK-HH">
<input type="hidden" id="amount_2" value="10.00">
 <select id="quantity_2" value="">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
</p>
<br>

<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.360mix.com/thankyou.html">
<input type="image" src="http://images.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but22.gif" border="0" name="submit" width="87" height="23" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user3368657 I am glad to help, Please remove your email, Anybody  anybody can see this sensitive information!

Comment: Thank you once again... this code works 100% for what I needed.. had to retype this to get rid of my email address as you suggested.